# Possibility that ubuntu machine infected by FTP malware

Tags: security

I know that this question might be duplicated but here is what happened.

Our web server got attack by injecting the spam links into server script file (Web server running Coldfusion9/.cfm/Window/IIS).

We blocked FTP access to only our office IP Address after the first attack and also change FTP password.

However, the attack is still going on after next few days. The hacker may came through other channel but I would like to make sure we have done best practice for Ubuntu security as we run Ubuntu on developer machine. (Connect to FTP via Eclipse Remote File System and FileZilla - no Wine installed)

- Would it be possible that hacker hacked to Ubuntu machine while the computer is running and connect to FTP to modify the file? 
  (They can't steal password and connect to FTP from their end because we Block all external access to web server except our single office IP, so hacking need to be happened in real-time if it come through FTP)
- Are there anything we can do to prevent/check this if it's the case?

Waking up at 2am at my timezone to fix the inflected scripts which I don't know when it going to happen again, this driving me nut. :(

Your help would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can advise you on how to block an attacker until you figure out how the attacker is getting access to your systems. To figure out how the attacker is gaining access, you will need to actively monitor the network from a system that has not been compromised, using some software like [snort](https://www.snort.org/).

If your Ubuntu system has been hacked then you will need to do a complete re-install, and change all user passwords and disable any trusted remote access methods (e.g. ssh trusted keys), and reset all user accounts. Otherwise you run the risk that a backdoor may be hidden in the operating system, filesystem or home directories.

Doing a proper post-compromise cleanup can be a lot of work. Whether it is worth doing depends on how much you value your security. I know one company where the management decided that they did not want to dedicate any resources to investigating a successful hack, even though they had no idea how the hackers got in, or how far they had compromised the network. The reality is that many companies end up in that situation.

Comment: "The reality is that many companies end up in that situation." I wonder how many of those companies would admit that to their users, customers, or stockholders.